# Wireshark Lua Dissector Response Request

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector, protofield

does someone know how to use the Protofield.framenu for frametype.RESPONSE and frametype.REQUEST for an arrow in wireshark with marks the Sequencenumber between an ACK and DATA?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's not yet possible to perform request/response tracking with Lua dissectors. [Wireshark issue 15396 - Add Lua support for tracking conversations.](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/15396) will track the progress of this feature though.